# How do I retrieve cucmber feature file names in a set of workspaces using Java

Tags: java, maven, reflection, cucumber

I have some set of cucumber feature files in different workspaces. ex: **a.feature ,b.feature** in projectA and **c.feature,d.feature** in projectB. I have to retrieve the names of the feature files using java from another projectC.

Results shoulb be as below.

a.feature

b.feature

c.feature

d.feature

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work to get files which files have the extension **feature**

```
File dir = new File((".//"));//+PACKAGENAMEVALUE.replace(".", "//")+"//"));
System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
String[] extensions = new String[] { "feature"};

List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
for (File file1 : files) {
   // System.out.println("file: " + file1.getCanonicalPath());
    bw.write("Cucumber Feature File Name:" +" " + file1.getName());
    bw.newLine();
}
```

you can get different types of file by modifying the following as below

String[] extensions = new String[] { "feature","jsp","txt"};